# How to manage user login history in Owin Context (in ASP.NET WebAPI)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

```
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var userManager = context.OwinContext.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

        if (user == null)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return;
        }

        ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
           OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager,
            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user.UserName);
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
        context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        user.Logins.Add(new IdentityUserLogin { UserId = user.Id, LoginProvider = "self",ProviderKey="" });

        await userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

    }
```

This is my code done.Now i want to manage the user's login history like LastLoginDateThis is my code done.

Comment: just put in the else part your custom implementation,